# Apache2 Permission denied - access to / denied because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Tags: apache2

I use apache and faced with permission problem on Ubuntu 21.04

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2021-06-17T17:09:41
```

sudo apache2ctl configtest returned Syntax OK

my logs

```
[Thu Jul 22 14:08:49.553904 2021] [core:error] [pid 33685] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:41084] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/ivan/hosts') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Thu Jul 22 14:08:49.609382 2021] [core:error] [pid 33685] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:41084] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/ivan/hosts') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://gpon-actual.local/
```

my host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gpon-actual.local
    DocumentRoot /home/ivan/hosts/gpon-actual
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gpon-actual-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gpon-actual-access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/ivan/hosts/gpon-actual">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I executed different suggestion but no of thous not helped

```
chmod +x hosts
chmod +rx hosts
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER hosts
sudo chmod 777 -R hosts/
```

In my /etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf I added

it was before

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and I just added after that additional:

```
<Directory /home/ivan/hosts/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

any idea ?

Comment: Have you given Apache access to `/home/ivan/hosts` in AppArmor?

Comment: how to check it  ?

Comment: If you have to ask, then AppArmor is either disabled (unlikely) or is blocking access to the `/home` directories. You can confirm its status with `aa-status`. You may need to edit the config for Apache in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2`.

Answer (score 5):

Just hit this on Ubuntu 22.04, Apache 2.4.52. The fix was simple. I needed to run:

```
chmod +x /home/<USERNAME>
```

Just having `755` on `/home/*/public_html` wasn't enough.

Answer (score 3):

The user [@John Heyer](https://askubuntu.com/users/1159107/john-heyer) gave [a correct solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417429/618353) to the problem on Ubuntu 22.04. I also had to do the following to make the app work:

```
 sudo chmod +x /home/
 sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/
 sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/my_laravel_site_folder/
 sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/my_laravel_site_folder/public/
```

And there you have it. A solution to a potential hair puller.